# Struct memory hack to overlap object reference - Is it possible?

Tags: c#, .net, performance, memory-management

I'm guessing the answer to this is going to be "It's not possible, switch to C++". But I thought I'd throw it out there anyway.

I'm dealing with a massive binary tree. I've got an array of structs to represent the branch nodes that I use to help with locality of memory when iterating through the tree.

To save a bit of memory, and therefore improve cache locality I'm looking at overlapping an object reference for leaf nodes. That object reference will point to all the leaf data. Basically, something like this:

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Explicit)]
struct BranchData
{
    [FieldOffset(0)] // 1 byte
    internal byte SplitIndex;
    [FieldOffset(1)] // 4 bytes
    internal float SplitValue;
    [FieldOffset(5)] // 4 bytes
    internal int LowIndex;
    [FieldOffset(9)] // 4 bytes
    internal int HighIndex;
    [FieldOffset(0)] // 8 bytes (We're working with x64 here)
    internal LeafData Node;
}
```

The above gives the following runtime error

> Could not load type 'BranchData' from assembly
>   'WindowsFormsApplication1, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=null' because it contains an object field at offset 0
>   that is incorrectly aligned or overlapped by a non-object field.

I could use a separate array to store the leaf data, and use the indexes to point to that array, but then I have 2 memory lookups (for what are certainly distant areas of memory). One for the location in the leaf array to get the reference, and one to get the leaf data. If I can achieve this overlap, I get rid of one of those lookups.

I am able to pin objects and use unsafe code to solve this problem. Speed is the key element here.

Comment: I might have an answer, but I have a couple of questions first:

1. Can you use unsafe code?  
2. If you cannot use unsafe code, can you pin the objects in memory?

Comment: @DanMcCann I can do either of those. I have no restriction on how dirty the code can be :-)

Comment: I am stretching the question here but could you move the problem to another place? Say you use [Neo4j](http://www.neo4j.org/) as your tree and get all the query goodness already written. Your possible performance problems will pop up somewhere else but might be easier solvable there. FWIW

Comment: The answer is, "No, you can't do that." The runtime won't allow you to overlay a reference type and a value type. I vaguely remember finding the relevant portion of the specification at one point, but don't recall where.

Comment: @WillCalderwood Did you ever manage to make this work?

Comment: @Anthony I'm afraid not

Answer (score 20, accepted):

This restriction is very fundamental in managed code.  The problem is that your *Node* member is an object reference.  A pointer at runtime.  It is overlapped by the other fields.

The garbage collector needs to be able to find that pointer back.  Necessary both to know that there's a live reference to the LeafData object on the heap.  And to update that pointer when the LeafData object is moved when the heap is compacted.

Problem is: there's no way that the collector can tell whether your union stores that pointer.  If it doesn't then there's a risk that the values of the other members will *look* like a valid object reference to the GC.  And that's very, very bad.

Storing an unsafe LeafData* is technically possible but that requires the LeafData object to be pinned.  That just can't work when the tree is big, the GC falls over when nothing can be moved anymore.  Storing the LeafData data in unmanaged memory is further down the rabbit hole, you are starting to write C++ code by then.  The only other thing you could do is store the LeafData in the node itself, as a struct, pretty unlikely you'll be happy with the fit.

Do note that you should avoid these misaligned fields, you'll get slammed pretty hard when a field spans an L1 cache line boundary.  Put the SplitIndex *after* HighIndex so this can't happen.

Comment: Thanks for that, it was the answer I was expecting. I was hoping there was something dirty I could do - maybe having two different struct types, and illegally slotting my second type into my array of BranchData using a pointer to a BranchData instance, making sure it was the correct size of course. Once I've got everything working, I may look at a C++ rewrite to speed things up with hacks.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if this is faster in practice, but it has fewer memory lookups in *managed* code.

(There might be more lookups in the CLR itself that I'm not aware of.)

That said, you can use `GCHandle` to overlay managed references with unmanaged data:

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Explicit)]
public struct Data
{
    [FieldOffset(0)]
    public IntPtr NativeData;
    [FieldOffset(0)]
    public GCHandle Handle;
}


Data data = ...;
((YourClass)data.Handle.Target).Blah();
```

Comment: The issue is not whether memory lookups are managed/unmanaged. It's just the fact they exist in the first place. Looking at anything that's not in the CPU cache is very slow which is why I need to cram as much as I can into a small space.

Comment: if we have offset same for two fields, isn't will cause data inconsistency which is there at that memory location?

Comment: @EhsanSajjad: Overlapping two fields itself isn't a problem -- you'll just read and write whatever value the overlapped portion is representing. However, in the case of managed types, it can confuse the garbage collector if it tries to follow a pointer that isn't actually a pointer. It's been 4 years so I don't remember what was in my head when I wrote this answer; for some reason it seems that I thought the garbage collector doesn't try to follow `GCHandle` and instead uses a lookup table elsewhere. So I can't really vouch for it anymore... hopefully someone can correct me if I was wrong.

Comment: i mean was if i have a struct with to int and both have offset 0 what does it acutally means?

Comment: i am just trying to understand the `FieldOffSet` thing

Comment: @EhsanSajjad: It just means you can read or write that memory location through either variable. If one of them was `int` and the other one was `long` then reading the `int` would give you whatever was in the first 4 bytes and reading the `long` would give you whatever was in the first 8 bytes. The computer is obviously capable of doing this and is happy to do it for you. Whether it is meaningful to your program is a different question and that depends on your program.

Comment: now i get it, that what i was looking for , thanks @Mehrdad :)